# How to get app id from moralis?

Tags: frontend, moralis

I've registered in moralis and i got my api key, Cli Api Key, and some other things, but when i want to use `MoralisProvider` i need a appId:

```
{/* <MoralisProvider appId={APP_ID} serverUrl={SERVER_URL}> */}
      <Component {...pageProps}/>
    {/* </MoralisProvider> */}
```

I have browsing in my panel but i can't find any appId, where is it located? how can i get this?

Answer (score 3):

Moralis has depreciated servers in favor of API's. All the core features of Moralis like web3 authentication and wallet, and contract syncs are now available through the API's. So it is now possible to add these features to any other backend like firebase.

As @b3hr4d mentioned using a self-hosted parse server is an option but it requires you to rely on depreciated Moralis sdk.

The newly released Moralis SDK is compatible with any backend so you can use more powerful backends like Firebase and AWS and also implement web3 authentication, wallet, and contract syncs into those backends. And overall the new SDK gives you more flexibility to use the Morlais features.

Check these docs for more details on how you can do that.
[Getting Started](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/getting-started) and
[Integrating into 3rd party backends](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/integrations)

You can visit their support at https://forum.moralis.io/ for further support in using Moralis.

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution for you @Alireza if you were starting a new project!

Answer (score 1):

They [discontinued](https://forum.moralis.io/t/retiring-servers-for-free-plan-users-from-1-december-2022/20657) the server, the only option is self-host a parse server.

https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/self-hosted-moralis-server/self-hosted-moralis-server#full-video-tutorial---hosting-integrating-migrating